# Swig simple type typedef argument

Tags: c++, lua, swig

I created C++ typedef for simple type in swig to lua, something like

```
namespace numbers {
    typedef float float4;
}
```

Also I created functions

```
numbers::float4 foo();
void foo1( numbers::float4 );
```

Lua code

```
result = foo()
foo1( result )
```

error:

```
 Lua error: Wrong arguments for overloaded function                                                                                                                                                                                           
   Possible C/C++ prototypes are:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
     foo1( numbers::float4 )
```

swig seems to recognize numbers::float4 but while creating lua variable it somehow gets confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Too long for a comment:

I cannot reproduce the issue in the question.  Can you try the following steps and see whether you still get an error?

I have the following C++ files:

**`test.hpp`**

```cpp
#pragma once

namespace numbers {
    typedef float float4;
}

numbers::float4 foo();
void foo1( numbers::float4 );
```

**`test.cpp`**

```cpp
#include <iostream>

#include "test.hpp"

numbers::float4 foo() {
    return 3.14f;
}

void foo1(numbers::float4 f) {
    std::cout << f << '\n';
}
```

And the lazy man's SWIG interface file:

**`test.i`**

```cpp
%module example

%{
#include "test.hpp"
%}

%include "test.hpp"
```

Then I generate the wrapper code and compile everything into a shared object.

```
$ swig -c++ -lua test.i
$ g++ -I/usr/include/lua5.2 -fPIC -shared test_wrap.cxx test.cpp -o example.so
```

The following example script runs fine.

**`test.lua`**

```lua
local example = require"example"
local foo = example.foo
local foo1 = example.foo1

result = foo()
foo1( result )
```

```
$ lua test.lua
3.14
```

Comment: Sorry, it was an oversight on my side. The example I provided was just an example. I have several .i files in my project and I forgot to add include in one of those, blaming other .i file for this. Thank you for your time, I really appreciate that.

Comment: @Mahashi I'm glad I could help.  That's why it is important to always create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).